# vb.net datagridview header right click event

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, header, right-click

I wonder whether there is datagridview header **right click** event in vb.net.

In my vb.net project, I have a datagridview, whenever I right click at the header part, the application will crash. Is there a way to avoid the crashing, for example add a event handler or any other approach?

Thanks.

The code related to the datagrid:

**UPDATE1**:

My code related to the datagrid as follows:

```
Private Sub Result_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("MyProject")
        logger.Info("Result_Load() - Start")

        Using connObj As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(My.Settings.dbConnectionString)
            connObj.Open()

            gridSql = "SELECT USER_ID, USER_NAME, USER_ADDRESS, USER_EMAIL FROM USER_DETAILS " & vbCrLf &
                      "WHERE USER_ID IN (" + Attribute.allUserSelected + ")"   
' the Attribute.allUserSelected is pass from another form

            logger.Info("gridSql= " + gridSql)

            Try
                adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(gridSql, connObj)
                adapter.Fill(ds)
                connObj.Close()
                DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        logger.Error(ex.ToString)

        Return
    End Try

End Sub


Private Sub dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.ColumnHeaderMouseClick
    MsgBox("click the header....") 
   'I can get the message here
    If (e.Button = MouseButtons.Right) Then
        MsgBox("right click the header......") 
        'cannot get this ,message, crash immediately
    End If
end Sub
```

Please advise me, thanks.

Comment: Does it crash without having any code at the event? If you've not defined the event this event won't execute any code. Maybe have you modified the drawing code?

Comment: Hi Btc, thanks for the quick reply. I even haven't found what is the event, I can only find the click event on the header, but not right click.

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: Hi all, just found a solution which mention just use ColumnHeaderMouseClick event to handle the right click event, will test it later and update the status.

Comment: Hi Btc and Jérémie, I have attach the code for the datagrid, any idea? thanks a lot!

Comment: Put a try/catch in your Column HeaderMouseClick, and a breakpoint on the "Catch Ex As Exception" line. Find out what the error code says, and then google that error code. It should help you.

Comment: Hi sparkysword, I add try/catch statement in the function and add breakpoint on the line of "Catch Ex As Exception", still the same. My project is a ArcGIS desktop add-ins, is this caused by the add-in? It seems I can never catch the right click on the column header.

Answer (score 0):

This is coming so late but it will not doubt help some people in the future

```
   DataGridView1. Columns ( 0). SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode. NotSortable
```

Your column headers won't respond to either `Left/Right Click`

Comment: Thank you BlackPearl, but I still need the sorting function in the datagridview.

Comment: You can make only the columns that are giving errors unclickable, the others will work just fine.

Comment: Hi BlackPearl, all the columns cause the issue. :(

Comment: I see, how do you wish to sort them? You want users to sort them or you just want to sort them programmatically?

Comment: Hi BlackPearl,I want user to sort them by clicking the column header. Thanks.